# GraphQL: how to avoid values overwrites for unspecified fields when doing an update via a mutation

Tags: java, graphql, null, mutation, spring-graphql

Let me explain:

I am using Gson as deserializer, MongoDB as storage and the newly Spring GraphQL

Let's say I have an object O in database with the fields:

```
A = 6
B = null
```

If the frontend send an update on the B field so I receive a JSON with only the B field with its value, so I receive O with:

```
B = 1
```

Then after deserialization, in Java my object O will have the following fields:

```
A = null
B = 1
```

Then, in MongoDB it will save:

```
A = null
B = 1
```

So the value of A will be overwritten by null, and we don't want that, the frontend only wanted to update the field B.

How do you solve that gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for "patchable entities" right now in Spring GraphQL. While the `null` vs. "empty" values for a field are accessible in the JSON map directly, binding that to a Java object and tying that up with the data Repository story is a bigger challenge.

This is being discussed in [this Spring GraphQL issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/228).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brian ! Is there any workaround in Java for that ? Do we know when the Spring GraphQL team will implement patchable entities ?